# I don't get meaning of $ symbol in this context

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's snippet which I been reference in book:

```
`photos/${Date.now()}.jpg`
```

I got curly brackets used to 'out of string', however mean of $ ...

ps: sincerely I also not want to ask question but I not know what I looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (template literals)

It will equal to `"photos" + Date.now() + ".jpg"`

Comment: Well, seem author in a hurry when put it into beginner book :) thanks!